# MS project link open ms project programme itself

Tags: ms-project

I have created a number of links on various pages on sharepoint that point to MS Project files sitting on a separate file share. 
A problem that is arsing when clicking on a link, MS Project is trying to open in a new tab of internet explorer - when what we really want it to do is open the MS project programme itself.

Is this there a setting within SharePoint or MS Project that will apply this??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need JS:

```
var appProject = new ActiveXObject("MSProject.Application.12");
 appProject.FileOpen(PathToProjectPlan);
```

Though, personally I've only ever used this for projects in Project Server, so there may be additional details for a file share. For example, for projects in project server, MS Project has to already be running and logged in for the above to work.  (and, for PS, the PathToProjectPlan looks like: 
`<>\\ProjectTitle`